# How to map intensity from dot product to float RGB from 0 to 1?

Tags: graphics, c, software-rendering

I'm getting the dot product of the surface normal and light position. The weird thing is the dot product is larger than 1.

Also, I want to map that intensity from 0->1 to Float RGB from 0->1. Here is my code related to the issue:

```
if (the_object->polys[curr_poly].shading == 1)
{
    // compute the dot product between the light source vector
    // and normal vector to surface
    normal.x = normal.x / Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);
    normal.y = normal.y / Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);
    normal.z = normal.z / Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);

    dp = Dot_Product_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal,
        (vector_3d_ptr)&light_source);

    // test if light ray is reflecting off surface

    if (dp > 0)
    {
        // now cos 0 = (u.v)/|u||v| or

        intensity = ambient_light + ( dp / (the_object->polys[curr_poly].normal_length));

        float r = the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.R*intensity;
        float g = the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.G*intensity;
        float b = the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.B*intensity;
        Color color = Color(r, g, b, 1);
        // intensity now varies from 0-1, 0 being black or grazing and 1 being
        // totally illuminated. use the value to index into color table

        the_object->polys[curr_poly].shade = color.ToUInt32();
}
```

Updated code:

```
bool bOnce = true;

float normx = normal.x;
float normy = normal.y;
float normz = normal.z;
float mag;
if (bOnce)
{
    bOnce = false;
    mag =Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);
}

// compute the dot product between the light source vector
// and normal vector to surface
normal.x = normx / mag;
normal.y = normy / mag;
normal.z = normz / mag;

dp = Dot_Product_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal, (vector_3d_ptr)&light_source);
```

updated code version 2 :

```
if (dp > 0)
                {
                    // now cos 0 = (u.v)/|u||v| or

                    intensity = ambient_light + ( dp / (the_object->polys[curr_poly].normal_length));

                    if (intensity > 1)
                        intensity = 1;
                    if (intensity < 0)
                        intensity = 0;


                    float r = (float)the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.R /intensity;
                    float g = (float)the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.G/intensity;
                    float b = (float)the_object->polys[curr_poly].color.B/intensity;
                    Color color = Color(r, g, b, 1);
                    // intensity now varies from 0-1, 0 being black or grazing and 1 being
                    // totally illuminated. use the value to index into color table

                    the_object->polys[curr_poly].shade =  color.ToUInt32();
```

calculating normal vector of the polygon

```
void calculateNormalLenth(Rasterizer *rasterizer, object* the_object, int index)
{
    unsigned int vertex_0, vertex_1, vertex_2;
    vector_3d u, v, normal;           // working vectors
    vertex_0 = the_object->polys[index].vertex_list[0];
    vertex_1 = the_object->polys[index].vertex_list[1];
    vertex_2 = the_object->polys[index].vertex_list[2];

    // the vector u = vo->v1

    rasterizer->Make_Vector_3D((point_3d_ptr)&the_object->vertices_local[vertex_0],
        (point_3d_ptr)&the_object->vertices_local[vertex_1],
        (vector_3d_ptr)&u);

    // the vector v = vo->v2

    rasterizer->Make_Vector_3D((point_3d_ptr)&the_object->vertices_local[vertex_0],
        (point_3d_ptr)&the_object->vertices_local[vertex_2],
        (vector_3d_ptr)&v);

    rasterizer->Cross_Product_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&v,
        (vector_3d_ptr)&u,
        (vector_3d_ptr)&normal);


    // compute magnitude of normal and store in polygon structure

    the_object->polys[index].normal_length = rasterizer->Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);
}
```

Comment: If the dot-product is larger than 1, normalize the vectors first.

Comment: I normalized the vector as shown above

Comment: You normalize `normal` but you don't seem to normalize `light_source` anywhere.

Comment: `normal.x = normal.x / Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);` and the two following lines aren't correct, calculate the length __once__ and use this one number for all three divisions.

Comment: @tkausl You could probably put all that into an answer.

Comment: Probalby, but these are just things I noticed, I'd rather not write an answer until I'm sure what I write solves the problem

Comment: @tkausl Would you put as answer with the solution please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

```
normal.x = normal.x / Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);
normal.y = normal.y / Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);
normal.z = normal.z / Vector_Mag_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal);
```

This is not normalization. After you divided x by the vectors length, the next call to `Vector_Mag_3D` will obviously calculate a new, smaller length, hence your vectors direction will change. Calculate the length **once** and divide all three axis by the same value.

---

```
Dot_Product_3D((vector_3d_ptr)&normal,
    (vector_3d_ptr)&light_source);
```

After you fixed the first problem, at least `normal` should be normalized, what about `light_source`? Is it normalized? If not, normalize it.

If both vectors are normalized, the dot-product *can only* result in a number between negative one and one. If you still got a bigger number, either the vectors are not normalized or your dot-product calculation is wrong.

Comment: see the updated code, is it correct ?  what about mapping the intensity to the color, is it correct too ?

Comment: That's hard to guess. Does the end result look correct on your computer screen?

Comment: Whats `the_object->polys[curr_poly].normal_length`? What values can `ambient_light` have? In your updated code, the normalization should be in the `if` aswell, otherwise you might divide by a uninitialized float and get garbage values when `bOnce` is false.

Comment: normal_length is a precomputed normal using 3 vertices, and ambient_light is 0.5f

Comment: But `normal_length` is a scalar, right? If thats the length of the resulting normal-vecor, shouldn't it be always one? (I might be wrong, though). Anyway, since the dot-product can be in the range `-1` to `1`, and if `ambient_light` is 0.5, and if `the_object->polys[curr_poly].normal_length` is `1`, then the range of `intensity` is `-0.5` and `1.5`. You should clamp it to `ambient_light` and `1.0` (since the intensity can not be lower than ambient intensity).

Comment: see updated code please. yes normal_length is scalar, see the updated code for calculating the normal scalar value